# Error running python program using UNIX cSh

Tags: python, unix

I was running a program for sorting data from a file using `counter` function.
So, quite obviously I put `from collections import Counter` at the top in my program.
Now the problem is when I was running my script with unix cShell then I am having an ERROR saying: "ImportError:Can not import counter" but the same program runs fine if I do it in MS-DOS.
I am using python 2.7.3

please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

`collections.Counter` is [new in Python 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html). Presumably your UNIX system has a lower version than 2.7.

Comment: @abhisek `python -V` will show the current version of Python you are using (mine is 2.6.5 under Ubuntu) and I get the same error with the import

Comment: @Daniel But I am using python 2.7.3 and also not working for me.